# ARKit and .dae file , strange space between object

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, blender

on my study project using ARKit and sceneKit I'm facing a strange behaviour when using .dae file.

i have created 2 object a cube and a plane with the following methods (both have physics):

```
  func loadBox() {
        let ballGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0.02)
        let mat = SCNMaterial()
        mat.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "ball")
        ballGeometry.materials = [mat]
        //Physic
        let physSchape  = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: ballGeometry, options: nil)
        let ballPhysic = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: physSchape)
        ballPhysic.mass = 100
        ballPhysic.friction = 0.8
        ballPhysic.isAffectedByGravity = true
        let nodeBall = SCNNode(geometry: ballGeometry)
        nodeBall.name = "ball"
        nodeBall.physicsBody = ballPhysic
        
        box = nodeBall
    }


func loadPlane(){
        let geometry = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "texture")
        geometry.materials = [material]
        // physics
        let physSchape  = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: geometry, options: nil)
        let planePhysic = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: physSchape)
        planePhysic.restitution = 0.0
        planePhysic.friction = 1.0
        planePhysic.isAffectedByGravity = true
        let nodo = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        nodo.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        nodo.physicsBody = planePhysic
        plane = nodo
    }
```

when I place the box over the plane in the scene they are correctly positioned and touching each other as you can see from the following picture:

[image: correct position]

**Here the problem:**

if i use a model downloaded from internet as .dae file of the plane, when insert it in the scene it create a strange space between the box and the plane (see picture)

[image: wrong position]

method I use to load the scn file.

```
  // load the elicopterBase
    func loadElicopterBase(){

        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "Model.scnassets/base.scn") else {fatalError()}
       
        guard let nodo = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Plane", recursively: true) else {fatalError()}
        // physics
        let physSchape  = SCNPhysicsShape(node: nodo, options: nil)
        let planePhysic = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: physSchape)
        planePhysic.restitution = 0.0
        planePhysic.friction = 1.0
        planePhysic.isAffectedByGravity = true
        nodo.physicsBody = planePhysic
        nodo.name = "base"
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.eliporto = nodo
            }
    }
```

Look like the .dae file have some sort of invisible boundingBox around it.
What or where I can look to find a solution to this.

here some picture of the .dae file in Xcode

[image: dae setting 1]
[image: dae setting 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your floor plane of type "concavePolyhedron" like so:

```
let body = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: yourGeometry, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's solve my issue.. but any reason why this?? if my file from blender is perfectly flat why should i add this? Thanks ..

Comment: it is not a blender issue. it is the way scenekit calculates and applys physics. by default physics bodies are not very accurate. concave polyhedron is the closest type that almost matches your real geometry... for more details ask apple :)

Comment: note: you cannot use concave polyhedron for a .dynamic physics body!